# How do i draw an Arrow in Java?

Tags: java

Here is what I am trying to create:

```
    *
    **
    ***
    **** 
*********
    ****
    ***
    **
    *
```

Here is what i have created:

```
*
**
***
**** 
**********
****
***
**
*
```

Here is my code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    if(i == 4){
        for(int f = 0; f < 5; f++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}

for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    for(int j = 4; j>=i; j--){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I dont know how to indent the tail part, please dont give me the answer, just tell me where the problem is and I will try to do it. Thank you!

Comment: You should also print the space as well. It is similar to other for-loop. Please try it again ;-)

Comment: How could you change the answer when I didnt edit mine? Some sort of magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the shape you have provided, and assuming it's going to be output in a monospace font, we can draw it on a grid.

[image: arrow on grid]

Splitting it visually into 2 sections, we can see that there are 2 main modes.

The tail (green), and the head (red).

[image]

There's also a second mode. where the number of stars in the head increase and decrease.

The size of the tail could potentially vary, as could the size of the head, and it would still be a shape we recognise as an arrow.

[image]

When outputting text, the easiest iteration order is generally left to right, up to down, unless dealing with right to left languages, or vertical reading, I'm going to assume western culture for the output, as that is what's been popularised in programming output streams.

So, the question is, how best to build up the strings required for output.

Given the format that the output is going to be on a stream,

width is going to be your outside loop, and tail/length your inside loop.

The code you provided uses 10 for width, by splitting it into 2 groups of 5, with the second one being offset by one.

[image]

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    if(i == 4){
        for(int f = 0; f < 5; f++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}

for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    for(int j = 4; j>=i; j--){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

so translating your code back to the drawings, you loop over width, and on the last iteration output the line of stars for the tail.

What you need to do, is output a space on all other lines.

There are a variety of ways to do so, you could output the character, or use one of the fixed width formatting functions using printf.

But given your current code, the minimal difference will be to output a space character, when the width iteration for the increasing mode is not 4, and for the loop of width - 1.

[image]

Looking at your end result, your tail is being printed after your head. That needs to move earlier.

Your tail is too long, need to offset that by 1.

And you need to insert pink and brown sections by printing spaces, the same amount of times as you output the tail, whenever you do not output the tail.

Comment: Without changing the angle, you can make it general for the width or length, but not both. Luckily OP didn't ask to make it general though, so I focussed less on it.

Feel free to improve it,  I don't get the rep, as it's a wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should add another inner for-loop that prints " " before the for-loop that prints "*".

Comment: as the number of spaces (or *) is know, why do you need a loop?

Comment: for it to be dynamic, say you want to increase the number of asterisk and space, you just have to increase the value of the condition in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` method to tell `Java` print in specific format. For example, you need 5 spaces prefixed then print your text:

`System.out.printf("%5s","hello");`

To get your desired output, try the below code. Note: There may be better solutions.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (i != 5) // middle line should not be prefix with spaces
        // empty 5 spaces before starting the loop
        System.out.printf("%5s", "");

    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (i == 4) {
        for (int f = 0; f < 5; f++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    // print 5 space before
    System.out.printf("%5s", ""); // <== note the printf here with empty string
    for (int j = 4; j >= i; j--) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method you can use to print the arrow:

```
private static void printArrow (final int min, final int max, final int tip)
{
    final int numSpaces = tip - max - 1;

    // print the top
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.println();
    }

    // print the tip
    for (int i = 0; i < tip; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();

    // print the bottom
    for (int i = max; i >= min; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Call it from main with**:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // this will print the arrow in your question
    printArrow(1, 4, 9);
}
```

**Another Example**:

```
printArrow(1, 10, 19);
```

**Outputs**:

```
        *
        **
        ***
        ****
        *****
        ******
        *******
        ********
        *********
        **********
*******************
        **********
        *********
        ********
        *******
        ******
        *****
        ****
        ***
        **
        *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. You just need to first insert the space and then print `*` until  you reach the middle line. If you want to make it dynamic, just replace the boundary value for `k` dynamically the same as the boundary for the `f`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 1;
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        m = i - 1;
        while (k != 6 && m != 4) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            k++;

        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (i == 4) {

            for (int f = 0; f < 5; f++) {

                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        k = 1;
    }

    k = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        while (k != 6) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            k++;

        }

        for (int j = 4; j >= i; j--) {

            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        k = 1;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
I realized the output is one`*` behind. So just need to change the boundary value of `k` from 5 to 6 (from the value of boundary for `f` to the value of boundary for `f`+1)
The output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Interesting that this is the accepted answer. It doesn't even print the arrow exactly as the OP wants it. The tip of the arrow sticks out 1 '*' too far

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis have fixed that tiny issue.

Comment: Especially interesting since OP specifically asked for the answer to not be given, like it was homework, yet the answer practically gave it to you.

Comment: I guess everyone here gave the answer. to best of my knowledge, giving the answer is the problem where the OP did nothing and want the answer from scratch.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach

Let me know how to explain it to the OP to make it for any value without this code.

Comment: @lonesome I saw you fixed it. Thanks. Can I help you?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis What kind of help do you exactly mean?

Comment: @lonesome I saw that you called me out in a comment, but since removed the comment. Not sure why?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis  `@RyanTheLeach Let me know how to explain it to the OP to make it for any value without this code. – lonesome 6 mins ago `

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (i!=5) {
            System.out.print("     ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (i == 4) {
            for (int f = 0; f < 5; f++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.print("     ");
        for (int j = 4; j >= i; j--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: instead of just for 5 how do i make it for every value,